# Turning on 'DEBUG' macro value

Tags: iphone

In my code, I want to conditionally perform a few operations with:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
NSLog(@"I'm in debug mode");
#endif
```

I've configured Project->Edit Project Settings->Build tab so that 'DEBUG' is listed as a User-Defined setting with a value of 1. Debug is selected in the Configuration dropdown. This still doesn't turn on the directive for the Debug build although I thought that's what it would do.

What else do I need to do during the build stage to allow for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set a compiler flag for that.

To do it, Get Info on the target, make sure you have selected the Debug configuration (and not All Configurations), and look for **Other C Flags** and **Other C++ Flags** (in Xcode 3.1 these are under *GCC 4.2 - Language*).

Then add the following as a value: `-DDEBUG` for both.

This will define the DEBUG for the precompiler to pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

project -> settings -> c/c++ (or code generation?) look for a text box labeled **Preprocessor Definitions** and just add DEBUG to the end of the comment separated list.

Comment: Is this in XCode? Don't see a C/C++/Code Generation menu option.

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions seem like SDK 3.0 solutions, I'm still living in a 2.2.1 world with XCode 3.1.

This [link](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/debugging/how-to-create-conditional-log-statements-in-xcode) did the trick for me, complete with pictures!