# In Objective-C, is there a RELEASE definition besides DEBUG?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Is there a `RELEASE` defined or maybe it is by another name?

I kind of not want to use

```
#ifndef DEBUG

#endif
```

because the `n` may be less obvious than if we use a `RELEASE`, which is quite clear.

If none is available, then is adding the following to `Support Files/project_name.pch` a good way to have `RELEASE` defined?

```
#ifndef DEBUG
  #define RELEASE 1
#endif
```

Comment: Very related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041193/turning-on-debug-macro-value

Answer (score 1):

`DEBUG` is just defined in Xcode's Build Settings under Preprocessor Macros. In that section you can specify macros to be defined for all builds, debug builds or release builds. Just add `RELEASE` to the release section and you have what you want; or if you prefer `#if` over `#ifdef` put `DEBUG=1, RELEASE=0` into the debug section and `DEBUG=0, RELEASE=1` into the release section.

(And if you're not using Xcode your build system/compiler should have similar facilities.)